# Not able to select a text under "span" using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click a channel link on this page,

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kaza+lol+highlights

```
<span class="style-scope ytd-channel-renderer">Kaza LoL LCS Highlights</span>
```

I tried,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Kaza LoL LCS Highlights']")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Kaza LoL LCS Highlights')]")).click();
```

But its not working. "unable to locate element". Please Help

Comment: Is your page fully loaded before you execute `findElement`?

Comment: I went by proposed link, and both xpaths You mentioned show 0 results. So, its natural, that elements can't be clicked. Build correct xpath at first.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to be clickable? Have you verified that the element exists on the page when you run your script? Need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the `Channel Link` **`Kaza LoL LCS Highlights`** you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='style-scope ytd-channel-renderer' and contains(text(),'Kaza LoL LCS Highlights')]"))).click();
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Can you please elaborate on what happened there ?? I'm completely new to this.

Comment: Well, 2 things, always give priority to `class` attributes because they mocks the `DOM`. If `class` attributes can't identify the element uniquely then start looking at the other attributes like `text()`. Finally, I am not sure about your previous steps, so it appeared to me the driver was running faster then the trailing `Web Client`. Hence induced `WebDriverWait`

Comment: My Bad.. Formatting error. Comment edit time over now.

Comment: Can you raise a new question please, I will immediately look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavascriptExecutor` to click the link

```
WebElement channelLink= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Kaza LoL LCS Highlights']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", channelLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code, it should work for you:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("channel-title")).click();
```

Above code will click the first item always, if you want to use customize the code to click based on text then you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@id='channel-title']//span[text()='Kaza LoL LCS Highlights']")).click();
```