# Not able to select a text under "div" tag using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click on a text enclosed in  tag,

```
 <paper-tab class="style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer" role="tab" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1"> 
<div class="tab-content style-scope paper-tab"> Videos 
</div> 
</paper-tab>
```

I tried this,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'tab-content style-scope paper-tab' and (text(),'Videos'))]"))).click();
```

I used the solution from this post by @DebanjanB which worked for the original post but not for this one.

[Not able to select a text under "span" using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742902/not-able-to-select-a-text-under-span-using-selenium)

Comment: Do you want to click on `Videos`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium and xPath - locating a link by containing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078308/selenium-and-xpath-locating-a-link-by-containing-text)

Comment: The problem is that "Videos" in this case has whitespace around it. The link above will show you how to adjust the XPath for this.

Comment: @DebanjanB, Yes I want to click on that. also please tell me why your previous method didnt work here.

Comment: It worked.. Thank you Debanjan. But will that be a unique identifier ??

Comment: @XOAD Definitely it will be. Let me know if you ever get stuck. I will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on **`Videos`** you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//paper-tab[@class='style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer']/div[@class='tab-content style-scope paper-tab']"))).click();
```

Comment: If you aren't searching for an element by the text contained in an element, you'd be better off using a CSS selector. They are faster, easier to read, easier to maintain, in many cases shorter, and in this case less fragile. When you match class names with XPath you are doing an exact string match which means if any of the classes change order, the locator will fail.

Comment: Also, I would take the time to eliminate any of the classes in the locator that aren't necessary... I'm guessing that all those classes aren't required to find the desired element. This will make your locator less fragile with small class changes to the page, etc.